# Secure Local Storage Angular 6

Tags: angular, express, events, local-storage, jwt

I have a question about secure of local storage for JWT. So I've added an event that handle events in local storage and when it listening from event of local storage it removes all data from it and after that redirecting into the login page. I just want to know, this will bring troubles in future or not. And if you know other ways to secure data of local storage from copying or changing. I'll be happy to know about that too.And one thing more I'm using MEAN for my application. Thanks for help and for attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of ways To secure this is to give a small lifeTime for your access tokens, you can implement a silent refresh token mechanism, so if someone copy your token it will not be valid for a longtime because of expiration and he can't get a new one

Comment: Thanks for response Fateh Mohamed.But  he or she(or maybe it) can use that before expiration, I want to break all ways for copying or changing the token.

Comment: another solution is to store your token in cookies instead of localstorage

Comment: check this https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/

Comment: The article is very helpful thank you very much.And for interest what you think about event that listening for local storage, is that good for more secure or it can bring troubles in production?

Comment: you can use something like  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-local-storage to get notified. can you upVote the answer :)